# Meaning of "credential mongering"

Tags: meaning, phrases, vocabulary

I couldn't clearly understand the phrase "credential mongering" as used in an article in the *New Republic* about the Ivy League. The extract, from "[The Trouble With Harvard](https://newrepublic.com/article/119321/harvard-ivy-league-should-judge-students-standardized-tests)" by Steven Pinker, is as follows:

> Admission to the Ivies is increasingly seen as the bottleneck to a pipeline that feeds a trickle of young adults into the remaining lucrative sectors of our financialized, winner-take-all economy. And their capricious and opaque criteria have set off an arms race of **credential mongering** that is immiserating the teenagers and parents (in practice, mostly mothers) of the upper middle class.

Is it to do with attaining qualifications by any means? Or is the phrase itself imprecise? Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Credential mongering** as it is used above implies a system of organizations who are actively promoting awards of dubious value implying the students who "earn" them will gain favor in the admittance process, rather than the awards being the product of a student following his or her passion and being rewarded for having done so.  The awards may not reflect much actual effort expended by the candidate; some students may be seeking out the easiest-to-earn awards just to increase their total count.  As such, they may be of dubious value in establishing relevant facts about the candidate's true desires or capabilities.

These candidates hope that the sheer quantity of awards will impress or sway the judges.

Comment: "implies a student who is actively seeking a quantity of awards primarily to gain favor in the admittance process". If mongering is being used in the normal sense—and I don't see a reason to assume otherwise—the implication is more that the institutions are selling/pushing (mongering) all kinds of credentials.

Answer (score 2):

"To monger" means to indulge in a disreputable activity, here trying by any means to establish for high-school students, "credentials" of achievement or status that would appeal to the admissions committees of these benighted institutions.

Comment: No, duchess, the OP's question was not about the word "monger," but I like you anyway, hence the upvote.

Comment: I'm afraid I can't return the favor.  The question was about "credential *mongering*."  Presumably if the OP didn't know what a credential was, he'd have titled his question differently.  Comments about Faraday and Einstein don't elucidate.  And if you need to refer to my royal heritage, please use the formal form of address -- "Your Grace".

Comment: The OP wanted to title the question differently but had to contend with a bout of second-guessing at the last moment. I protest the comments about Faraday and Einstein do more than merely elucidate: they throw an ocean of light where thitherto darkness reigned. "Duchess" is romantic; "Your Grace" might be misconstrued. You wouldn't want people to think you're an archbishop.

Answer (score 1):

***What is a 'monger' and what is 'mongering'?***

I think that from a logical perspective the phrase "credential mongering," as used by Steven Pinker, puts the situation backwards; but the published evidence doesn't support my opinion. The verb *monger* has a simple definition in *Merriam-Webster's Eleventh Collegiate Dictionary* (2003):

> **monger** *vt* (ca. 1864) : PEDDLE

The verb form comes from the noun *monger*, which has been in English since before the twelfth century. Again from the *Eleventh Collegiate*:

> **monger** *n* (bef. 12c) 1 : BROKER, DEALER — usu. used in combination {ale*monger*} 2 : a person who attempts to stir  up or spread something that is usu. petty or discreditable — usu. used in combination {war*monger*}

But the arms race that teenage students and their parents are engaged in is not, during what the author of the excerpt suggests is the period of immiseration, a matter of sales but of acquisitions: the students (and their parents) are trying to collect as many credentials as they possibly can, in hopes of outportfolioing the competition when college admissions application time rolls around.

I think it would make perfect sense to refer to this process as a "credentials arms race" or as "credential stockpiling" or perhaps as "credential gorging," but in the context of high-school students and their drive to acquire credentials, "credential mongering" would make more sense if it referred to individuals or institutions (standardized-test-prep operations, businesses that offer unpaid internships, volunteer organizations, etc.) that offer students the shiny credentials they so desperately desire in return for some price in money, labor, or both.

Obviously the author of the OP's quoted extract views the meaning of the term differently—as though the acquirers of the credentials are the mongers.

---

***How have writers used 'credential mongering' since 1978***

I ran a Google Books search to see whether "credential mongering" is an established phrase with a settled meaning. The search returned 13 unique matches, none earlier than 1978. The earliest is from "[Jack Hodgins and the Island Mind](https://books.google.com/books?id=0UAnAQAAIAAJ&q=%22His+work+has+color+and+humor.+It+has+a+rich+literacy.%22&dq=%22His+work+has+color+and+humor.+It+has+a+rich+literacy.%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjhu_Lt2ajJAhULwGMKHZ88BbsQ6AEIHDAA)," in *Book Forum*, volume 4 (1978) [combined snippets]:

> His work has color and humor. It has a rich literacy and intellectual depth, and yet it is uncluttered by the pretentiousness of compulsive and overbearing **credential-mongering** which so often accompanies straining attempts at those qualities.

Here 'credential-mongering" seems to mean something like "parading one's erudition before one's readers in an effort to shock and awe them into stunned admiration"—or in short, "credential flaunting."

Interestingly, "credential mongering" comes up most often in the context of criticism by pro-evolution scientists of creationist scientists. For example, from [*The New Scholasticism*](https://books.google.com/books?id=zXUXAQAAMAAJ&q=%22credential+mongering%22&dq=%22credential+mongering%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjqzeGP16jJAhVCMYgKHRnsCwsQ6AEIYDAJ), volume 59 (1985) [combined snippets]:

> In a sixth chapter section [of *Abusing Science: The Case Against Creationism* (1982)] entitled "**Credential Mongering**" [Philip] Kitcher reveals that, despite advanced science degrees, most "leading" creation scientists are not biologists and none are serious contributors to biological sciences. Nevertheless, the Fundamentalist motivation and lack of credentials should not mislead us to expect that rebuttal of the Creationist arguments, especially the negative ones, is an easy task.

From Charles Taylor, [*Defining Science: A Rhetoric of Demarcation*](https://books.google.com/books?id=NdkDiqh5ySYC&pg=PA158&dq=%22credential+mongering%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjqzeGP16jJAhVCMYgKHRnsCwsQ6AEISjAF#v=onepage&q=%22credential%20mongering%22&f=false) (1996):

> Creationists, of course, are not reticent about proclaiming their "legitimate" status in a tactic that Kitcher aptly labels "**credential mongering**" (1982, 178). Those credentials presumably sanctioned the scientific legitimacy of the degree holders because, as Dolby pointed out, "formal scientific institutions limited themselves to the higher parts of cultural hierarchies by setting *minimum* standards for participants in their activities" (1982, 273).

From Evan Selinger & ‎Robert P. Crease, [*The Philosophy of Expertise*](https://books.google.com/books?id=c6mP5H0l_XUC&pg=PA144&dq=%22credential+mongering%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjqzeGP16jJAhVCMYgKHRnsCwsQ6AEIUDAG#v=onepage&q=%22credential%20mongering%22&f=false) (2006):

> Moreover, to make matters at the very least somewhat more difficult for the nonexpert, "creation scientists" are quit careful to proclaim their own credentials *as scientists*. Indeed, the very use of the terms 'creation science' and 'Christian science' are efforts at establishing credentials. Philip Kitcher criticizes creation scientists for just this kind of "**credential mongering**":
>
> > <sup>Creationist claims about credentials look better when presented in soft focus. ... On closer inspection, the "21 scientists who believe in Creation" [listed in a creationist publication] hardly constitute a distinguished panel of experts on the origin of life: three hold doctorates in education; two are theologians; five are engineers; there is one physicist, one chemist, a hydrologist ... one entomologist, one psycholinguist, and someone who holds a doctorate in Food Science Technology. finally, there are two biochemists ... an ecologist, a physiologist, and a geophysicist. While the last five may have some expertise in related areas, the credentials of the others are utterly irrelevant to many of the questions Creationists address. ...</sup>

From Donald Prothero, [Evolution: What the Fossils Say and Why It Matters](https://books.google.com/books?id=R2MaAwAAQBAJ&pg=PA16&dq=%22credential+mongering%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjqzeGP16jJAhVCMYgKHRnsCwsQ6AEIPzAD#v=onepage&q=%22credential%20mongering%22&f=false) (2007):

> **4. Arguments From Authority and Credential Mongering**
>
> Many people try to win arguments by quoting some "authority" on the subject in an attempt to intimidate and silence their opponents. Sometimes they are accurately quoting people who really are experts in a subject, but more often than not, the quotation is out o context and does not support their point at all, or the authority is really not that authoritative. ...
>
> In particular, it is common for people making extraordinary claims (like creationism or alien abductions or psychic powers) to wear a PH.D. (if they have one) like a badge, advertise it prominently on their book covers, and feature it in their biographies. They know that it will impress and awe the listener or reader into thinking they are smarter than anyone else or more qualified to pronounce on a topic. Nonsense! Unless the claimant has earned a Ph.D. *in the subject being discussed*, the degree is entirely irrelevant to the controversy.

And from Massimo Pigliucci & ‎Maarten Boudry, [*Philosophy of Pseudoscience: Reconsidering the Demarcation Problem*](https://books.google.com/books?id=Pc4OAAAAQBAJ&pg=PA353&dq=%22credential+mongering%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjqzeGP16jJAhVCMYgKHRnsCwsQ6AEIOjAC#v=onepage&q=%22credential%20mongering%22&f=false) (2013):

> **Credential mongering.** Another red flag is when an author makes a claim and waves his credentials in front of us to intimidate us by his “authority.” This is particularly common in creationist books that flaunt the author's PhD on the cover, but it occurs even in science when a fringe scientist-author wants to be taken seriously. When you see "PhD" on the cover of a book, it is often an indicator that the book cannot stand on the strength of its own arguments and evidence.

In at least one instance, creationists tried to turn the "credential mongering" label back on their foes. From Alice Kehoe, [*Militant Christianity: An Anthropological History*](https://books.google.com/books?id=A58URq1ZeP8C&pg=PA131&dq=%22credential+mongering%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjqzeGP16jJAhVCMYgKHRnsCwsQ6AEIRTAE#v=onepage&q=%22credential%20mongering%22&f=false) (2012):

> Beginning in 1961, the Gablers spoke to the [Texas textbooks] board, to politicians, and to PTAs and churches, attacking evolution as unsupported theory and finding numerous mall errors of fact in history texts. Their lack of academic credentials—Mel had one year of college, Norma none—seemed of no consequence to them; their website states:
>
> > <sup>Q. Who are the analysts chosen to go over the textbooks in question, and what qualifications have they?</sup>
> >
> > <sup>A. This **credential mongering** is an ad hominem tactic to dodge inconvenient criticism. If points raised are valid, what matters the source?</sup>

Outside the creationism-vs.-evolution conflict, other writers used the phrase "credential mongering" in a similar sense of showing off one's various seals of approval. From Charles Peters & Jonathan Alter, [*Inside the System*](https://books.google.com/books?id=egekasQSzdgC&q=%22credential+mongering%22&dq=%22credential+mongering%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjbyKXO5ajJAhULfogKHW5_DqM4ChDoAQguMAA) (1985) [combined snippets]:

> I don't mean to make too much of it, but it does seem possible that even something so obviously dumb as Success Motivation International does a better job than Harvard Law School of infusing people with the sort of aspirations that the country most needs right now. People of talent should not be devoting their lives to **credential-mongering**, but the merit racket constantly encourages that. We need, instead, new machinery aimed at encouraging and rewarding *results*, not potential.

From Hedrick Smith, ed., [*The Media and the Gulf War*](https://books.google.com/books?id=TZ5tAAAAMAAJ&q=%22credential+mongering%22&dq=%22credential+mongering%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjbyKXO5ajJAhULfogKHW5_DqM4ChDoAQg2MAI) (1992) [combined snippets]:

> [Peter] Arnett's champions, such as his friend David Halberstam, rebutted with **credential-mongering**. They reminded us of Vietnam, where Arnett won a Pulitzer Prize, and spoke of his integrity and his courage. The nature of his current coverage was hardly mentioned. Opponents of the war (yes, there really were some back in January) also came to the defense, in hopes perhaps that reports like Arnett's might produce a Vietnam effect.

And finally from [*Chinese American Forum*](https://books.google.com/books?id=kAMQAQAAMAAJ&q=%22credential+mongering%22&dq=%22credential+mongering%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjbyKXO5ajJAhULfogKHW5_DqM4ChDoAQg5MAM), volume 11 (1995) [combined snippets]:

> Once I overheard one of my graduate students compare value of various academic degrees. You all know what B.S. means right? "Basic stuff." M.S. means "more—stuff." And PH.D. stands for "piled higher and deeper."Despite this type of cynicism, our culture seems to be rampant with **credential mongering**. Every year millions of high school students shop for the fanciest designer label diploma that they or their parents can afford. Recently I saw a sweatshirt emblazoned with "Polo University" and I wondered where I could get a diploma signed by Ralph Lauren.

Here, at last—and perhaps also (though less clearly) in the Peters & Alter (1985) instance—we see the use of "credential mongering" not in the sense of "credential flaunting" but of "credential acquiring." But even here, the context is presented as a shopping spree for a diploma from a high-prestige institution, not as an exhausting and soul-numbing competition for credentials to be parlayed (each competing student hopes) into one of an extremely limited number of slots at a university seen as a possible means of entry into the ruling class.

---

***Conclusions***

On its face, "credential monger" looks like a natural synonym for "diploma mill" (for example)—a seller or broker who deals in credentials. But the term seems never to have been used that way, to judge from Google Books search results. Instead, it has been used primarily to refer to showing off one's paper credentials or actual accomplishments in order to impress gullible audiences. A few instances involve instead the notion of wasting one's time chasing superficial accomplishments rather than achieving substantive goals involving actual knowledge or concrete real-world results.

In contrast, the *New Republic* quotation that the OP cites portrays "credential mongering" as a breathless, never-enough, misery-inducing chase after credentials in order to outcompete equally determined and miserable fellow students for a few open spots at the top of the educational food chain. It seems to me that this particular application of the phrase puts it to work with a meaning that it did not previously have.

In one sense the mongering metaphor kicks in accurately—if you think of the student citing credentials in his or her college admissions applications as resembling a fishmonger trying to outshout other nearby fishmongers about the excellence of his or her haul. But ultimately, the image is backward: in reality, the student has collected credentials like battered coins of dubious worth and is trying to persuade the fishmonger to accept them in return for one of the stall's few really big fish.

Answer (score 0):

Credentials, not achievements. All true achievements can be viewed as credentials. One couldn't call everything that passes for credentials these days "achievements" while keeping a straight face.

Certificates of all kinds do play a role. However, being an assistant to someone known to the school in some project can go a long way. A recommendation letter from a one-time graduate who is now a senator (good) or benefactor (better) is certainly a plus, though hardly an achievement in the purely technical sense.

While it is quite true that nothing might ever happen unless one has a highly concerned and persevering Mom, the Ivies are hardly ignorant, ruthless, or arrogant. Scholarship for superachievers from public high school are not unheard of. Academic excellence is, of course, favored over actual talent and ability, but one can't blame the schools for it: in an epoch of mass education they don't have much else to go by. The fact that Faraday had no formal education to speak of, or that Einstein was a lousy student, is hardly their concern: their job is to turn out educated people, not geniuses.

Answer (score 0):

In this context **credential mongering** refers to the obsession of the mothers over the interpretation of whimsical acceptance critteria. I can see your confusion because the term implies the credential has already been earned, but I think the author has just used the term a bit awkwardly.